# Axis is crooked

Tags: axis

The axis for all of my object manipulations seem crooked.

[image: The axis problem itself]

Comment: can you show us you UI without using a tool? You probably have Local or Normal Orientation enabled, but i can't tell from this image, since the tool information is replacing those icons/buttons.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug. I have reported this many times. No fixes yet.
It happens after you applied *deltas to animated keyframes*. Then your axis will not respond to normals, world, local or anything else.

The only solution here is to extract faces of the mesh with <kbd>P</kbd> (part them) and then reconstruct them again by "Join" <kbd>J</kbd>

Then you will have your pivot point again in a fixed correlational position with the other joined elements.